# Searching for a state address

Tags: php, parsing

I am trying to parse some webpages to detect the presence of U.S. states on the page. The trouble i am running into is that the state i have is abrieviated and the string match on the page is returning false positives. For example, if the search is for AZ and the word amaze is on the page, the result is positive for the presence of the state of Arizona. My code snippet is below:

```
//$state = "AZ";
    if (stristr ( strip_tags ( $response ), $state ) != FALSE) {
        $stateMatch = true;;
    }
```

How can i best do this type of parsing? I would ideally also like to search for the full state of "Arizona" given that the $state variable is storing the corresponding abbreviation (AZ)?

Comment: Highly likely you'll always get false positives because of states like Maine which is abbreviated as "ME" - quite a common word in English (also OK for Oklahoma, OR for Oregon).

Comment: is there any clever regex or some other form of string matching that can reduce the false positives? I mean theres got to be something better than straight up string match for AZ

Comment: If you are trying to match it on the entire page instead of in a specific element you most likely are out of luck and you will have better chance by outsourcing it to late people do it manually. Or wait for the [singularity](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FTechnological_singularity&ei=8SngUpS1KqyT0QWB8IGYCQ&usg=AFQjCNGzsRQukKAzZL1J-Ci3vB9hoEK0eg&sig2=SXsOypLLaYMRr1f8_28FFQ&bvm=bv.59568121,d.d2k). To at least improve it a bit match based on word boundaries. Which obviously would still be crappy.

Comment: Simply parsing for state abbreviations in large amounts of text is never going to be reliable. You could improve it by searching for proximity to formatted addresses, but even that will only get you so far.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this scenario once. What I did, like, if I wanted to search AZ, I thought what could come before  AZ. If it is the really a state code and not any other word like amaze, there could be space or comma or semicolon or bracket, etc. before AZ. In short, AZ can not have any alphabet before it otherwise it is any other word not code for Arizona so you can check that the character before AZ should not be alphabet.

I narrowed my search to search follow instead of just AZ because in my case I could only have following combinations 
 AZ 
,AZ 
(AZ 
;AZ

Answer (score 0):

I think you are out of luck, unless your mandate that the state abbreviation is followed by a period

```
// $state ='AZ.'
```

or know reasonably well that there will be a space before the abbreviation and a space or period after it.

```
// $state = ' AZ '
// $state = ' AZ.'
```